# Extreme value theory？

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, extreme-value

I am studying probability and finding hard to understand the following equation.

$Pr[P_i \leq \min\{P_s;s \neq i\}]=\int_0^\infty \underset{s\neq i}{\prod}[1-G_s(p)] \, dG_i(p)$

where $P_i$ are random variables, $G_i(p)$ is a cumulative distribution function $G_i(p)=Pr[P_i \leq p]$

Could you explain me how to get the right side of the equation? what theory dose it use? Thank you!

Comment: IOt is impossible to understand your question until you define your terms! We are not mindreaders here.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: For any given $p$, ask yourself "what is the chance that $P_i$ is approximately equal to $p$ *and* all the other $P_s$ exceed $p$?"  This will help you understand the right hand side.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has not responded to questions